# Nginx config as reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, kubernetes

I need to configure nginx as reverse proxy. It should allow access to /phpmyadmin with a reverse proxy to private_ip:5000.
This is part of nginx.conf:

```
location ~ /phpmyadmin {
   rewrite ^.*\/phpmyadmin(\/?)(.*)$ /$2 break;
   proxy_pass        https://192.168.99.6:5000;
   proxy_redirect     off;
   proxy_set_header   Host $host;
}
```

And this config works except in cases:

1. https://192.168.99.6:5000/phpmyadmin. But with a `/` at the end, that's okay.
2. I get a 404 error after logging in, but if I press "back" everything is fine.
3. I also get 404 error after logging out.

Please help me fix this. All services are in the k8s cluster.

Answer (score 1):

It's not immediately obvious what the goal is here.

If the backend service is listening with a URI that matches /phpmyadmin and you have a location block for /phpmyadmin in your nginx config, then it should be entirely sufficient to simply put:

```
location /phpmyadmin {
  proxy_pass https://192.168.99.6:5000;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

If the goal is to *drop* the /phpmyadmin URI segment, then something like:

```
location /phpmyadmin/ {
  proxy_pass https://192.168.9.6:5000/;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

From my understanding of your description you don't actuallt need the rewrite at all.

Comment: This is a training project that aims to understand all of these technologies. Without rewriting, in the first case, it turned out 404, in the second - 502.